# Configure route on Synology NAS with iptables

Tags: routes, iptables, nas, synology

I have a Synology NAS and I want configure routing on it: nat with port forwarding.
Googled I found that it is possible with iptables, but I didn't found web interface for it.

So, my question is do you know how to configure nat with port forwarding on DSM 5.0 with web interface and is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to DSM via telnet or SSH.
Using the root account with the password to login to CLI(The same CLI on other Linux distro)

Using the iptables command to add new rules.

You need a sysnology NAS with 2 LAN ports for NAT purpose.